# Can't add Android platform to Cordova project as 'the command "android" failed'

Tags: macos, command-line, android

I'm having trouble adding the Android platform to my Cordova project. When attempting to add the platform, I get the following error:

> Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.

I have already installed PhoneGap and I believe the error is in my PATH. I downloaded the bundle and my path is as follows:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```